# Smarter way of counting values in object (JS, React)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reactjs

Taking a look at the code below, is there a better way of getting the count of items that contain a certain key/value pair inside of a react state?

This method seems like it could cause a bottleneck once the list that I'm going through becomes large.

Here's a simplified example of the question at hand:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.state = {
      animals: [
        {type: 'cat'},
        {type: 'dog'},
        {type: 'cat'},
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="app">
        <Categories state={this.state} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Categories extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.countItems = this.countItems.bind(this);
  }

  countItems(type) {
    var count = 0;
  
    for(var i = 0; i < this.props.state.animals.length; i++) {
      if(this.props.state.animals[i].type === type) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    
    return count;
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="categories">
        <div>Total animals: {this.props.state.animals.length}</div>
        <div>Cats: {this.countItems('cat')}</div>
        <div>Dogs: {this.countItems('dog')}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this is a method you would call often, then it might be useful to index your data (animals) by type, and keep that updated whenever you make changes.

For instance:

In the `App` constructor you would create another property `animalsPerType`:

```
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      animals: [
        {type: 'cat'},
        {type: 'dog'},
        {type: 'cat'},
      ]
    };
    this.state.animalsPerType = this.state.animals.reduce(function(acc, animal) {
        return acc.set(animal.type, (acc.get(animal.type) || []).concat(animal));
    }, new Map());
  }
```

Then your `countItems` method becomes trivial:

```
  countItems(type) {
    return this.props.state.animalsPerType.get(type).length;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not change the structure of your state, then you must do some sort of loop through and count by type.

A more expressive approach might be to use reduce:

```
countItems(type) {  
    return this.props.state.animals.reduce((acc, next) => {
        return next.type == type ? acc + 1 : acc)
    }, 0);
  }
```

However, if performance is a problem:

1. You could keep the count in state and calculate once each time `animals` change
2. You could split each type of animal into a separate array in state and then use `length` on each.
3. Changing your state to something like this might help:

`this.state = { animals: { dogs: [], cats: [] } }`